# Not able to launch kubernetes dashboard deployed via helm due to certificate issue

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-dashboard

I am very new to the kubernetes and learning kubernetes via google and social platforms. I am facing issue in launching kubernetes dashboard which I deployed recently using helm.

#### Setup

Cluster set up via vagrant using virtual box with nodes running ubuntu 18.04.

Kubectl version v1.13.0

Helm Version:"v3.1.2 installed on Windows 10 Powershell via chocolaty.

#### Problem statement

I have deployed kubernetes-dashboard using helm command from repository stable/kubernetes-dashboard version 1.10.1. I have used NodePort to expose Kubedashboard service but when I try to connect to kubernetes-dashboard on my local windows system via Chrome I get the below error.

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 192.168.5.21 (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

vagrant@master-1:~$ curl -vvv https://192.168.5.21:32224
* Rebuilt URL to: https://192.168.5.21:32224/
*   Trying 192.168.5.21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.5.21 (192.168.5.21) port 32224 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

I want to understand why application is generating self-signed certificate and not using CA certificates from master nodes. Can you please help me in resolving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: did you provide a commercial CA cert...otherwise it will generate a self signed

Comment: I haven not given manual input while installing via helm. 

What I see in the deployment.yaml in the repository which i downlaoded :- 

{{- if .Values.enableSkipLogin }}
          - --enable-skip-login
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.enableInsecureLogin }}
          - --enable-insecure-login
{{- else }}
          - --auto-generate-certificates